# Add fields to model without permit param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am trying to add fields to a model directly from the controller action without a form,only the user_id is saved the other columns (firstname,lastname) are empty each time i run the code, below is the code, note: User has_many :provide_helps.

```
@firstname=current_user.firstname
@lastname=current_user.lastname

@gh_user = User.find_by status: 'gh'
@ph = @gh_user.provide_helps.create(firstname: "#{@firstname}" , lastname: "#
{@lastname}")
```

Comment: could you show us the `ProvideHelp` model code ? also pay attention that `@gh_user.provide_helps.create` will create a `ProvideHelp` on this user not a new user with firstname and last name, and by the way why all `@` vars ? are you going to use them in views ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@ph = @gh_user.provide_helps.create(firstname: @firstname , lastname: @lastname)
```

No need to assign `@first_name` and `@last_name` using `#{}`.

Comment: Thanks bro, just what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the code below:

```
@gh_user = User.find_by(status: 'gh')
@ph = @gh_user.provide_helps.new({ firstname: current_user.firstname, lastname: current_user.lastname })
@ph.save
```

or

```
@gh_user = User.find_by(status: 'gh')
@ph = @gh_user.provide_helps.new()
@ph.first_name = current_user.first_name
@ph.last_name = current_user.last_name
@ph.save
```